# Mapping of address => uint256 in Struct returning wrong value after transaction in test

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testing

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract TestContract is SafeMath {
    struct Result {
        bytes32 name;
        uint256 balance;
        mapping (address => uint256) betBalances;
    }

    function TestContract(bytes32[] _resultNames) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < _resultNames.length; i++) {
            results.push(Result({
            name: _resultNames[i],
            balance: 0
            }));
        }
    }

    function getBetBalance(uint resultIndex) public validResultIndex(resultIndex) constant returns (uint256) {
        return results[resultIndex].betBalances[msg.sender];
    }

    function bet(uint resultIndex) public hasNotEnded payable {
        Result storage result = results[resultIndex];
        result.balance = safeAdd(result.balance, msg.value);
        result.betBalances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(result.betBalances[msg.sender], msg.value);
    }
}
```

Here is my testing code:

```
const web3 = global.web3;
const TestContract = artifacts.require("./TestContract.sol");

contract('TestContract', function(accounts) {
    const params = {
        _owner: accounts[0],
        _name: "test",
        _resultNames: ["first", "second", "third"],
        _bettingEndBlock: 1000
    };

    let testContract;

    it("allows users to bet if the betting end block has not been reached", async function() {
        testContract = await TestContract.new(...Object.values(params));

        testContract.BetAccepted().watch((error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Event Error: " + error);
            } else {
                console.log("Event Triggered: " + JSON.stringify(response.event));
                console.log("resultIndex: " + JSON.stringify(response.args._resultIndex));
                console.log("betAmount: " + JSON.stringify(response.args._betAmount));
                console.log("betBalance: " + JSON.stringify(response.args._betBalance));
            }
        });

        let initialBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(testContract.address).toNumber();
        let betAmount = web3.toWei(1, 'ether');
        let betResultIndex = 0;

        await testContract.bet(betResultIndex, { from: accounts[1], value: betAmount });
        let newBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(testContract.address).toNumber();
        let difference = newBalance - initialBalance;
        assert.equal(difference, betAmount, "New result balance does not match added bet.");

        let resultBalance = await testContract.getResultBalance(betResultIndex);
        assert.equal(resultBalance, betAmount, "Result balance does not match.");

        let betBalance = await testContract.getBetBalance(betResultIndex);
        assert.equal(betBalance.toString(), betAmount, "Bet balance does not match.");
    });
```

And here is the console error:

```
/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:213982
        throw reason;
        ^
AssertionError: Bet balance does not match.: expected '0' to equal '1000000000000000000'
    at /Users/xxx/coding/xxx/test/topic.js:75:11
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

**I have confirmed the bet method works by adding an `Event` and that the `betBalance` is as it should be (not included in this code). But it is returning as 0 on the testing side. Why is this happening?**

I know that transactions aren't able to return values, but is my call to get the resultBalance considered a transaction since I am chaining the call?

Comment: Please either post all your solidity code, or narrow this down to a simpler demonstration of the error that others can reproduce.

Comment: Updated post to include simple testable code.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the `bet` method is working properly? You're not saving the local `result` object back to the main mapping (`results[resultIndex] = result`), so it may not be getting saved properly?

Comment: @MidnightLightning Yes I am sure it is working properly. I have an `Event` that I use to return the value of `results[resultIndex].betBalances[msg.sender]` and it properly shows the correct balance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your msg.sender is not the same. In the first call you use { from: accounts[1] .. In the second you don't. When you don't specify the account taken is accounts[0]

Comment: You are correct @decanus. Actually I figured this out right after I set the bounty lol. But, good catch! You earned it!